# Really Strange Behaviour on Trackpad/Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, macos, mouse, trackpad

Macbook Pro / Sierra /Model 1502

1. My Touchpad stopped clicking. I could move the pointer around but couldn't click. Then I plugged in an external mouse. Still couldn't click but the right click worked somehow on the external mouse.
2. After a lot of struggling I managed to disable the Touchpad by using this command 
   `sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBMultitouch.kext` . Then the external mouse started to work normally.
3. But now the keyboard started to act strange. Some letters don't work, some do work but very slowly. Then I connected an external keyboard and it works fine.

Now I am using external keyboad/mouse and have the Touchpad disabled.

Can someone help me to make the original keyboard/touchpad work again. What is the root cause of this weird behaviour.

p.s. I have tried all kinds of reboots.
  * Command+Option+P+R
  * Option+Control+Shift

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/295164/edit) your question to provide the exact model of Mac you're using? It'd also be good if you can clarify what *I have tried all kinds of reboots* actually means - otherwise you may get a whole heap of irrelevant answers.

Comment: When external devices work correctly, its often a good infication of hardware damage to the internsl ones.

Comment: @Allan That question doesn’t have a keyboard issue. Just a trackpad one. Also, the mouse didn’t work when just disabling the trackpad over there.

Comment: @DonielF - the keyboard (internal) is connected to the USB bus.  Plugging in external devices and disabling the internal ones solves the issue because it's no longer recognizing errant input from the track pad. A stuck button on a mouse/trackpad can create the symptoms we are seeing here.

Comment: @Allan My feeling is that just because two sets of symptoms are caused by the same problem doesn’t make them duplicates. Two people have a broken DVD drive; one has one that doesn’t open and one has one that won’t read the disc. Would you classify those as dupes? (Bad example, I know, but it should sufficiently illustrate my point.)

Comment: @Allan When I disable the touchpad then internal keyboard behaves strangely as described in the question. Can this be attributed to the same issue in your opinion. If so I will order an new touchpad.

Comment: The first thing you want to do is diagnostics outside of macOS.  Run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.  What this will do is tell us whether it's a hardware issue or a software issue.  Then we go from there.

Answer (score 0):

This happens all the time for various reasons. Typically, you want to disable Bluetooth and disconnect all usb devices. Then verify that you only pair or connect one device at a a time.

> if one device has left mouse pressed down, you can’t ever get a left mouse up event from any other device.

Bluetooth interference or less commonly, faulty usb devices can overload the communications channel and you can isolate this by connecting devices one by one.

[Why can't I left click on my Macbook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232039/why-cant-i-left-click-on-my-macbook-pro)

The last two times I had this affect me was a second Magic Trackpad pinned under a book on a bookshelf and an old but reliable (up to when it failed) USB 2.0 hub.